# Which token standard should be use to create different tokens for different users?

Tags: tokens, erc-721, erc-1155, nft

I have read several differences between fungible and non fungible tokens. It cleared my few doubts though, I have few more remaining.

I have requirement to create a platform on which users can register and create their own token with passing token name, price and so. Is it possible to develop such contract to create different token for different users? And which token standard should be used in this scenario ERC721 or ERC1155

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I have requirement to create a platform on which users can register and create their own token with passing token name, price and so. Is it possible to develop such contract to create different token for different users?*

- Using [OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts) you can create either a fungible token ERC1155 or a non-fungible token ERC721.
- In case you want each platform user to have a unique token then go for ERC721 else ERC1155 / ERC20.
- I would recommend you to go with ERC20 as the OpenZeppelin community has already kept in place the ERC20 token development and openzeppelin is one of the prominent battle-tested library when it comes to smart contract development.

*And which token standard should be used in this scenario ERC721 or ERC1155*

- If each user should have a unique token plus the token should be non-tradeable then ERC721 else ERC1155 / ERC20 as stated above.

Comment: Thanks for your response! can we create a smart contract that will issue new ERC20 tokens for each user?

Comment: Yes, we can create a contract that issues new ERC20 tokens. For instance if you create the contract that issues token to be MasterContract.sol using OpenZeppelin then calling MasterContract's mint() function with the user's address will issue new tokens to the provided user's address. 
mint(userAddress, amount)
For further clarifications check out mint() function of openzeppelin.

Comment: Thanks! And is there any good code example to do the same for ERC721 tokens?

Comment: Understanding ERC721: https://kauri.io/understanding-openzeppelin-erc721/9a7a50e503a1477f8b91397ecf1677da/a
Simple ERC721 Example: https://medium.com/coinmonks/a-simple-erc-721-example-c3f72b5aa19

Comment: If you can help on this: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/82106/39618